# How do I add a route for a new Refinery CMS admin action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms

I have a refinery extension that I created that manages Fieldtrips for a school.

My current fieldtrips_controller for the admin side has the following.

```
module Refinery
  module Fieldtrips
    module Admin
      class FieldtripsController < ::Refinery::AdminController

        crudify :'refinery/fieldtrips/fieldtrip', :xhr_paging => true


        def destory_pin
            @pin = Refinery::Pins::Pin.find(params[:id])

            if @pin.delete
                render :json => {result: "success"}
            else
                render :json => {result: "error"}
            end
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see I added a method for destroying what I'm calling a pin, witch is a model that I have associated with fieldtrips.

I'm using an ajax request from my Fieldtrip edit page. the url I'd like to call would be "refinery/fieldtrips/destory_pin

currently in my routes file for fieldtrips I have the following

Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.append do

```
  # Frontend routes
  namespace :fieldtrips do
    resources :fieldtrips, :path => '', :only => [:index, :show]
  end

  # Admin routes
  namespace :fieldtrips, :path => '' do
    namespace :admin, :path => 'refinery' do
      resources :fieldtrips, :except => :show do
        collection do
          post :update_positions
          post :destory_pin
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Currently when I run `rake routes` I get the following

```
POST    /refinery/fieldtrips/destory_pin(.:format)                                 refinery/fieldtrips/admin/fieldtrips#destory_pin
```

If I nav to /refinery/fieldtrips/destory_pin in my browser I get a NoMethodError in Refinery::Admin::BaseController#error_404

I'm sure I'm doing the routes wrong and need suggestions on how to correct this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `member` instead of `collection`, e.g.

```
namespace :fieldtrips, :path => '' do
  namespace :admin, :path => 'refinery' do
    resources :fieldtrips, :except => :show do

      collection do
        post :update_positions
      end
      member do 
        post :destory_pin
      end

    end
  end
end
```